# Vue: how to delete item from api

Tags: javascript, vue.js

in vue js i have categories below came from api, and i created an admin that can delete those categories from api using remove button, my problem is the splice i used here is not removing it from json file, is there a way to do it? and thanks in advance
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```html
<template>
<b-button
              
 size="sm"
  variant="outline-secondary"
  v-for="(category, index) in posts.categories"
:key="index"
   @click="RemoveAllSelected(category)">X Remove all</b-button>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "postComponent",
  components: {},

  data() {
    return {
      categories: [],
      selectedIndex: [],
      AddedCategory: [],
      error: [],
      

      posts: {
    description: null,
        questionTitle: null,
        question_file_path: null,
        categories: null,
        reviewed: false,
  
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
 
     RemoveAllSelected(categories) {
         this.selectedIndex.splice(categories._id);},
    
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `splice` takes the `index` of the item in the array and delete count. Take a look at the documentation here:

[Array.prototype.splice documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

What you can do instead of using `splice` (and a better practice of doing this) is to reset the `selectedIndex` in your data with a filtered version:

```
this.selectedIndex = this.selectedIndex.filter(item => item !== categories._id)
```

But what I understood from the code, you want to remove all categories, under the `posts` object. In this case, instead of mutating `selectedIndex` you have to set the `this.posts.categories` to an empty array in your `RemoveAllSelected` function:

```
RemoveAllSelected(categories) {
   this.posts.categories = []
}
```

Comment: Do you keep just category ids in `selectedIndex`? can you share what your `selectedIndex` looks like when it's not empty? @sara97

Comment: I updated the answer, try the second part I added @sara97

Comment: thank you but also didn't work, ithink cuz the items i wanted to delete are from api that why it's not working

Comment: your answer removes them when i click remove button but it's not updating the api

Comment: Yes, any kind of client-side solution will not affect your server-side functionality or the data in your database. So, you should implement this on server-side and on button click you should call to the backend to make it happen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226623/discussion-between-meghdad-hadidi-and-sara97).

Comment: you mean delete api url?

Answer (score 0):

```
   @click="RemoveAllSelected(index)"
```

@click method just pass index and slice item based on index on your `RemoveAllSelected` method `this.posts.categories.slice(index, -1)`

Comment: in your data property `posts.categories:[]` set empty array not null let's try one more time also if you want to make sure you want to set some custom object on your categories not from API then delete. if works then try to set from API there some Reactivity related issue.